# Remove window title bar in TKinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I remove the title bar from a Toplevel() window in Tkinter.
Right now I for my main I have

```
    self.master.title("Subtest")
    self.master.geometry("400x200")



    self.alertwindow()


    Label(self.master,textvariable=self.connected,height=4).grid(row=0,column=0)


    Button(self.master,text="Monitor",command= lambda: self.startnewthread(1),width=10).grid(row=6,column=1)
    Button(self.master,text="Quit",command=self.haltprogram).grid(row=6,column=0)
```

And for my alert window function I have

```
def alertwindow(self):
self.listbox=Listbox(Toplevel(self.master,width=150).overrideredirect(True),width=150).pack)
```

I was wanting the program to open up a root window, and then a toplevel listbox without a title bar; however, the only thing the program is doing right now is freezing, and when I remove the .overrideredirect(True), the program launches two listbox windows.  How can I have the program open only one listbox without a title bar on windows?  Thanks

Comment: do you need to actually call `pack` in the last line of code you posted?  `Listbox(Toplevel(...).pack())`  As it is, you're passing a method where `Tkinter` expects a `Widget`.  I'm not sure what that would actually *do* when you try to run the program, but it wouldn't be what you want it to do in any event...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this line

```
self.listbox=Listbox(Toplevel(self.master,width=150).overrideredirect(True),width=150).pack)
```

It's pretty clear you're trying to do *WAY* too much on 1 line.  (Your parenthesis don't even match).  Let's break it up, shall we?

```
new_top = Toplevel(self.master,width=150)
new_top.overrideredirect(True)
self.listbox = Listbox(new_top,width=150)
self.listbox.pack()
```

Also note that you seem to be using `.grid` and `.pack` -- Generally that's ill advised and `Tkinter` will happily spend all of eternity trying to negotiate a proper placement of a widget when you try to use them together.

---

My guess about what's happening:

- your actual code has properly balanced parenthesis so there is no SyntaxError
- Toplevel.overrideredirct returns None
- Listbox sees None as the parent widget and substitutes the root widget (`Tk`)
- Then you're using `.grid` and `.pack` both on the root widget which causes your program to hang.

Comment: Everything works! Thanks a lot.  I swapped everything over to .pack and followed your code and now everything functions properly. Thanks!

Comment: @user1161439 -- Great!  Glad to be helpful.  Note that you probably don't need to switch everything over to `pack` if you are very careful to not `pack` and `grid` on the same frame/toplevel (I believe).  It's just that the hang you experienced was probably a result of using `.grid` and `.pack` on the same widget (`Tk` most likely) and that happened because you were trying to do too much at once.  I don't advise creating a widget and placing it in the same line in general -- I don't find that it makes the code easier to read, but in some circumstances it could be ok I suppose...